# import hausdorff.distances as distances ImportError: No module named distances

Tags: python, python-2.7, pytorch

I am using python 2.7 and I use the

```
from hausdorff import hausdorff
```

I get this error although I am using pip2 install hausdorff and it syas requirements already satisfied.

```
    from hausdorff import hausdorff
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hausdorff/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .hausdorff import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/hausdorff/hausdorff.py", line 3, in <module>
    import hausdorff.distances as distances
ImportError: No module named distances
```

Comment: It looks like the `hausdorff` package is broken.  In particular it seems to be mixing relative and absolute imports in a way that might not work.

Comment: so what is the solution if so?

Comment: Submit a bug report?  It's possible your installation is also broken somehow.